# Patchwork: collect legend with different underlying values

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, patchwork

I want to collect legends for 9 ggplots using the `patchwork` package. The legends have different underlying values (See Fig. 1) but all correspond with the same value labels (See Fig. 2). Is it possible to collect these legends? Using `plot_layout(guides = "collect")` does not work.

**Fig. 1**

[image]

**Fig. 2**
[image]

The code I am using:

```
library(patchwork)

(p1 | p2 | p3 | p4) / (p5 | p6 | p7 | p8 | p9) &
   scale_color_brewer(labels = c("-2 SD", "-1 SD", "Mean", "+1 SD", "+2 SD"),
                      palette = "RdYlBu") &
   scale_fill_brewer(labels = c("-2 SD", "-1 SD", "Mean", "+1 SD", "+2 SD"),
                     palette = "RdYlBu") &
   plot_layout(guides = "collect")
```

**Minimal Working Example**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
plot1 <- ggplot(data = mtcars %>% mutate(cyl = as.factor(cyl)),
                mapping = aes(x = wt, y = mpg, group = cyl, color = cyl)) +
   geom_smooth(method = "lm")


plot2 <- ggplot(data = mtcars %>% mutate(cyl = as.character(cyl)),
                mapping = aes(x = wt, y = mpg, group = cyl, color = cyl)) +
   geom_smooth(method = "lm")

plot1 + plot2 &
   plot_layout(guides = "collect")
```

[image]

**Desired Outcome of MWE**
[image]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick just added a MWE that I believe works to reproduce this problem - thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't resolved this, you need to use the `+` instead of the `&` in your code:

From your mwe:

```
# note the +
plot1 + plot2 + plot_layout(guides = "collect")
```

[image]